# Why is my Audio not playing inside a Table TD?

Tags: javascript, html

Idk why but my audio doesn't start playing when i hover over my

Here is the code HTML :

```
<tr><td class="nav"><a href="https://myanimelist.net/anime/20/Naruto"><img src="naruto.png" draggable="true" id="dragelement1" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" alt="Naruto" height="125px" width="125px" ></a><audio id="beep" preload="auto"><source src="naruto.mp3"></source></audio></td></tr>
```

and the Function :

```
<script>

var beepOne = $("#beep")[0];
      $(".nav").mouseenter(function() {
        beepOne.play();
      });

</script>
```

Comment: Could the problem be, that you are declaring the var as "BeepOne" and are trying to call "beepOne.play()" (with lowercase 'b')?

Comment: no , i changed that , still same

Comment: try removing the "[0]" behind the selection of the "beep"-Id. Usually the selection of an ID returns a single object, while the selection by class returns an array of objects.

Comment: still not working :c

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is null

which means $(".nav") is null

Comment: That's odd, that part is working when I try it. I will post my working test as an answer so you can check your code against it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your Error, following is the code that works fine for me. When I hover over the element, I can hear the specified sound file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="nav">
                <a href="https://myanimelist.net/anime/20/Naruto">
                    <img src="naruto.png" draggable="true" id="dragelement1" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" alt="Naruto" height="125px" width="125px" >
                </a>
                <audio id="beep" preload="auto">
                    <source src="naruto.mp3"></source>
                </audio>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script>
            var beepOne = $("#beep")[0];
            $(".nav").mouseenter(function() {
                beepOne.play();
            });
    </script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmm that's so weird , why my code is working for you but not for me ?

Comment: did you insert the script tag at the end of the body? If not, that could explain the "Uncaught TypeError"

Comment: i inserted them before closing the </body>

Comment: In that case I sadly really have no idea where the problem could be, Im sorry

Comment: i removed the " $" and used instead "jQuery" .. the error is gone but the audio still doesn't seem to trigger .. By what i wrote it should play audio when i hover over that image that is located in the <a> atribute right ?

Comment: if i try to use autoplay="true" the file is recognized and the html will send the sound . So it must be something wrong with the Function ? but it doesn't give any errors